# Proper .htaccess redirect code

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, redirect

I need help to redirect old URL to new URL by using .htaccess.

I code my website by using CakePHP. Initially, I didn't change pagination URL structure. So my URL looking like this. This is just an example, actually it contain a lot more sub-directory & pages.

```
http://www.web.com/abc/
http://www.web.com/abc/page/page:2/
http://www.web.com/abc/page/page:3/
...
...
http://www.web.com/def/
http://www.web.com/def/page/page:2/
http://www.web.com/def/page/page:3/
...
...
http://www.web.com/ghi/
http://www.web.com/ghi/page/page:2/
http://www.web.com/ghi/page/page:3/
...
...
```

Many people say this is not good for SEO, so I change my URL structure to be like this. The coding is CakePHP is all done.

```
http://www.web.com/abc/
http://www.web.com/abc/page/2/
http://www.web.com/abc/page/3/
...
...
http://www.web.com/def/
http://www.web.com/def/page/2/
http://www.web.com/def/page/3/
...
...
http://www.web.com/ghi/
http://www.web.com/ghi/page/2/
http://www.web.com/ghi/page/3/
...
...
```

What I need to do next is to redirect my old URL to the new URL. I need help on the proper code which can redirect all my URL without doing it one by one.

Really appreciate any help on this. TQ

Comment: [**You better of changing CakePHP routing to change that, instead of using .htaccess.**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html)

Comment: Already done that. Just need to redirect old to new URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well something like this should work

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/page:([0-9]+)/$ /$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: TQVM. Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/page:([0-9]*)(.*)$ /$1/page/$2$3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: TQVM. It work but I have to modify a little bit to RewriteRule ^(.*)/page:([0-9]*)(.*)$ /$1/$2$3 [R=301,L] to do what I really wanted